# Maps with a nested vector

Tags: c++, vector, maps

For some reason the compiler won't let me retrieve the vector of integers from the map that I've created, I want to be able to overwrite this vector with a new vector. The error the compiler gives me is ridiculous. Thanks for your help!!

The compiler didn't like this part of my code:

```
line_num = miss_words[word_1];
```

Error:

```
[Wawiti@localhost Lab2]$ g++ -g -Wall *.cpp -o lab2
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:156:49: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘miss_words.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::vector<int> > > >((*(const key_type*)(& word_1))) = line_num.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back<int, std::allocator<int> >((*(const value_type*)(& line)))’
main.cpp:156:49: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat->linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2vector:70:0,
                 from header.h:19,
                 from main.cpp:15:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/vector.tcc:161:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/vector.tcc:161:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void’ to ‘const std::vector<int>&’
```

CODE:

```
map<string, vector<int> > miss_words;       // Creates a map for misspelled words
string word_1;                  // String for word;
string sentence;                // To store each line;
vector<int> line_num;               // To store line numbers

ifstream file;                  // Opens file to be spell checked
file.open(argv[2]);

int line = 1;
while(getline(file, sentence))          // Reads in file sentence by sentence
{
    sentence=remove_punct(sentence);    // Removes punctuation from sentence
    stringstream pars_sentence;     // Creates stringstream
    pars_sentence << sentence;      // Places sentence in a stringstream
    while(pars_sentence >> word_1)      // Picks apart sentence word by word
    {
        if(dictionary.find(word_1)==dictionary.end())
        {
            line_num = miss_words[word_1]; //Compiler doesn't like this
            miss_words[word_1] = line_num.push_back(line);
        }       
    }
line++;                     // Increments line marker
}
```

Comment: In `miss_words[word_1] = line_num.push_back(line);`, `line_num.push_back(line)` returns `void`, and then you are trying to assign this to `miss_words[word_1]`, which is a `std::vector<int>`, no?  The last compiler line states `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void’ to ‘const std::vector<int>&`.

Comment: Right, so how would I retrieve the vector that has been stored in the map?

Comment: @wawiti `miss_words[word_1]` returns a reference to the vector.  You can use that, and there's no need to copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a copy(ies) of the vector, which is unnecessary.

```
line_num = miss_words[word_1];
```

Should instead be:

```
std::vector<int> &v = miss_words[word_1];
v.push_back(line);
```

This should also address the same issue RyanMck pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

No, the compiler is complaining about the line after what you think:

```
miss_words[word_1] = line_num.push_back(line);
```

The function `std::vector::push_back()` returns `void`.  You cannot assign that to a `vector`.

Instead of copying your vector out, pushing a value, and then copying it back in, why don't you just push straight into it:

```
miss_words[word_1].push_back(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line_num = miss_words[word_1]; // use assignment operator to assign value at key word_1 to line_num
miss_words[word_1] = line_num.push_back(line); // trying to reset the value at key word_1
```

As RyanMcK stated, push_back returns void.

Rewrite above two lines (simpler, correct and you are not copying any data using the assignment operator):

```
miss_words[word_1].push_back(line) // directly access the value at key word_1
```

This works because std::map::operator[] returns a reference to the mapped value.

Sources:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/)